# How much screen space do you need for swiping?

Tags: android

I have an Activity with two Fragments, where only one Fragment is shown at the same time. But the user can swipe between them.

The left Fragment is a MapFragment, and the user is able to scroll and zoom this as normal. But when the user starts a swipe touching the rightmost part of the screen, it will scroll to the other Fragment instead of scrolling the map.

In other words:

```
if (motionEvent.getX()<myFragment.getWidth()-SOME_VALUE) {
    scroll the map
} else {
    switch to the other Fragment
}
```

My question: **What is a good value for the constant SOME_VALUE?** Are there any system defined constants I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: SOME_VALUE should be a percentage of your screenwidth, for example 10%. 
Most important is to test this on an actual device. I'm not sure if the user finds your described behaviour logical (I think I wouldn't).

I myself would probably choose a small menu bar at the top of the screen to be able to switch between the fragments. Then your swipe has become very simple without having to choose what to do depending on the position that started the swipe.

Comment: I ended up using 10% of screen width, but minimum 50 and maximum 100 pixels.